# Function in a function to find the zero of a function

Tags: python, function, mathematical-optimization

Here is the relevant code.

```
from scipy import optimize
```

I have a first function returning a float as a function of an argument (also a float) and some default parameters. Mathematically speaking, this the function mapping argument to float has a unique zero.

```
def function0(argument,otherParameters=default):
    ...
    return ...
```

Then I have a second function returning the unique zero of the first function.

```
def function1(otherParameters=default):
    def local(argument):
        return function0(argument)
    return optimize.root(local,0,tol=1e-6).x[0]
```

My problem is that I then have to call function1 a great number of times, and I feel that my method is far from optimal.

I thought about a binary search to find the zero I am looking for, but my guess is that optimize.root should be optimized and probably faster that a simple binary search.

Still, I guess that defining a function in another function is where my method lacks efficiency.

In short: is there a more efficient way to deal this?

Comment: We can't help you much without more details about the `function0` function

Comment: I don't think the details in ```function0``` are relevant, it is juste a real function without an explicit zero.